# How do I get Jquery plugin Grider to recalculate the grid when I AJAX change a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a great working grid, dynamically populated from my database, powered by Grider, but when I AJAX change a grid value via document.getElemtnById, the cell value in the grid changes, but Grider does not recalculate using that value like it does when you enter your own value.

**How can I make Gridr recalculate the grid once my document.getElementById AJAX updates the value of a cell?**

Gridr: https://github.com/boriscy/grider/

```
    for ($num = 0; $num<=5; $num++){
print "<tr>
            <td style=\"display:none\"></td>
            <td>
                <select name=\"det[$num][item]\" onChange=\"getitemprice(this.value,$num);\">
                    $item_select
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name=\"det[$num][price]\" id=\"price_$num\" type=\"text\" class=\"num\" value=\"10\" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name=\"det[$num][quantity]\" type=\"text\" class=\"num\" value=\"1\" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name=\"det[$num][discount]\" type=\"text\" class=\"num\" value=\"0\"  />
            </td>
            <td style=\"display:none\"></td>
            <td class=\"num\">
            </td>
        </tr>

";
```

}

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#table1').grider({countRow: true, countRowAdd: true});
```

});

Comment: I would like to suggest to you to try to find a newer/more up to date plugin. This plugin hasn't been updated in **5 years**. I've looked though the plugin and, at first glance, there is no method for updating the sizes. There also wasn't anything on destroying the plugin. I would highly suggest you look into something more recent/active.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up just using:

```
document.getElementById('price_' + row).value = 200;    
$('#price_' + row).trigger('change');
```

grider needed a trigger to calculate everything again, so I just made a trigger and it fired grider!

done.